# PhoneGap build + jquerymobile: onclick on button does not work

Tags: jquery, button, cordova, onclick

I developed a mobile application using jquery mobile. On a particular page I try to call a javascript function via a "onclick" on a button.

All works perfect in Safari on the iPhone when hosted online.
http://laughlouder.onesixtydev.nl/star/batna.html

But when I build the app via PhoneGap build (online), the button is frozen.
Im not sure if PhoneGap build of the app uses the same Safari browser for this web view. But what ever I try, the link wont work.

Tried this:
`<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="doSetItem();" data-ajax="false">`

And this:
`<a href="#" data-role="button" onclick"doSetItem();">`

Strange thing that is works in Safari, but not via PhoneGap build. What is the difference anyway?

Tried putting the function in document ready, or loading it via onload in the body all does not make a difference. Googling for days now, and nobody seems to have the same problem.

Who can help?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? This issue is driving me up the wall.

Answer (score 0):

you should use tap event instead of click.

```
 <a href="#" data-role="button" ontap"doSetItem();">
```

http://digitalize.ca/2010/02/jqtouch-tap-vs-click/

http://www.bagonca.com/blog/2010/06/18/use-tap-events-instead-of-click-events-in-iphone-browser/

Comment: Seems very likely, unfortunately it does not work. Tried with ontap, ontouch and onClick. The onClick works on the mobile safari browser. The ontap en ontouch don't. But onclick also does not work when builded via Phonegap.

Comment: did you try add event handler by jQuery?